# React native af-video-player gives has no proptype

Tags: react-native, video

Im facing video`has no proptype for native prop`rctvideo.onvideoaudiobecomingnoisy`of native type`bool` in react native af player

in android its work fine problem occurs in IOS platform

your help is highly appreciated.
Thanks

```
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Video
                    onFullScreen={status => this.onFullScreen(status)}
                    fullScreenOnly={true}
                    placeholder={placeholder}
                    //url={videoUrl}
                    url={detailedWorkout.videoLink}
                    rotateToFullScreen={true}
                    theme={theme}
                    volume={1}

                />
            </View>
            {content}
        </View>
    );
```

[image: problem]

Comment: please share your code

Comment: This is somewhat weird. I come across the prop on RCTVideo called onAudioBecomingNoisy. But not on*Video*AudioBecomingNoisy. Are you sure you have no typo's in your won implementation somewhere?

Comment: nope buddy, before the af player I tried react-native player.after your comment I remove react native video and delete all the code(relevant to video player) and node modules  and try af player again, but didn't work same error occurs

Comment: It says, Native version and JS version are not of same version. Try reinstalling the app. Try restarting the npm.

Comment: thanks for the comment Ashwin and all,I moved to the react-native-video since I have limited time to find a solution. My problem was with react-native-video is that some Android phones not supporting and in emulator not showing any video, I explain the situation to management and they are okay to move with react-native-video since react-native-af-player can't play any video in IOS( in my case). I didn't found any solution for this case